# NSNotification vs. Delegate Protocols?

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iPhone application which basically is getting information from an API (in XML, but maybe JSON eventually). The result objects are typically displayed in view controllers (tables mainly).

Here is the architecture right now.

I have NSOperation classes which fetch the different objects from the remote server. Each of these NSOperation classes, will take a custom delegate method which will fire back the resulting objects as they are parsed, and then finally a method when no more results are available. So, the protocol for the delegates will be something like:

```
(void) ObjectTypeResult:(ObjectType *)result;
(void) ObjectTypeNoMoreResults;
```

I think the solution works well, but I do end up with a bunch of delegate protocols around and then my view controllers have to implement all these delegate methods. I don't think its that bad, but I'm always on the lookout for a better design.

So, I'm thinking about using NSNotifications to remove the use of the delegates. I could include the object in the userInfo part of the notification and just post objects as received, and then a final event when no more are available. Then I could just have one method in each view controller to receive all the data, even when using multiple objects in one controller.†

So, can someone share with me some pros/cons of each approach. Should I consider refactoring my code to use Events rather then the delegates? Is one better then the other in certain situations? In my scenario I'm really not looking to receive notifications in multiple places, so maybe the protocol based delegates are the way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your design sounds sound. The clear Cocoa approach is using delegates, and is much preferred to throwing objects around. Also, defining your protocols this way makes your code very explicit and easy to understand. All in all: keep up the good work